# Server Temporarily Unavailable When Running as Eclipse Application

Tags: eclipse

When I try to run my project as an Eclipse application, it fails every time with this error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide 2 17 2019-08-06 15:20:08.729
!MESSAGE Server ‘org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide.server’ failed with exception: Service Temporarily Unavailable. ; version: 2.0.7.v20170906-1327
!STACK 0
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Service Temporarily Unavailable
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.HttpResponses$ProgressMonitorResponseHandler.handleResponse(HttpResponses.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.HttpResponses$ProgressMonitorResponseStringHandler.handleResponse(HttpResponses.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.HttpResponses$ProgressMonitorResponseStringHandler.handleResponse(HttpResponses.java:1)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Response.handleResponse(Response.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.HttpResponses.getContentWithProgress(HttpResponses.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.IO.refreshConfiguration(IO.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.ServerConnection.startUp(ServerConnection.java:124)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:62)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:122)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my run configuration:
[image]
I've looked at a [bunch](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1079389/) [of](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493524) [threads](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-24534) about similar problems, but I couldn't solve the issue.

My Eclipse version is Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) running on Windows.